# Writing Yesod test case for handler with an id parameter, where id is a key to an Entity

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have been following the yesod tutorial and I am stuck on how to build a unit test involving parameters in a view that also hit a database.  Backtracking a little, I followed the Echo.hs example:

```
    getEchoR :: Text -> Handler Html
    getEchoR theText = do
        defaultLayout $ do
            $(widgetFile "echo")
```

The corresponding test, note I have to cast the parameter into Text using Data.Text.pack

```
    yit "Echo some text" $ do
        get $ EchoR $ pack "Hello"
        statusIs 200
```

Now I have the model defined like so:

```
Tag
    name Text
    type Text
```

With a handler that can render that that obviously take a TagId as the parameter

```
    getTagR :: TagId -> Handler Html
    getTagR tagId = do
        tag <- runDB $ get404 tagId
        defaultLayout $ do
            setTitle $ toHtml $ tagName tag
            $(widgetFile "tag")
```

This is where the test fails.

```
    yit "Get a tag" $ do
        -- tagId is undefined
        get $ TagR tagId
        statusIs 200
```

I am not sure how to define the tagId.  It wouldn't work with a String or Text or Num, and I can't seem to figure out how to generate one as I can't find any example code in various Data.Persist tutorials.  Or better yet, some other way to call the `get` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [Key](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/persistent/Database-Persist-Types.html#v%3aKey) data constructor to construct an ID value, which takes a `PersistValue` as a parameter. A simple example of creating one is:

```
Key $ PersistInt64 5
```

Another option is to call `get` with a textual URL, e.g. `get ("/tag/5" :: Text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since times have changed, I'll leave this note here to say that these days one would use something like:

```
fromBackendKey 5
```

See the docs for [fromBackendKey](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.21/persistent-2.8.2/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:fromBackendKey).